# Unable to encrypt/decrypt file data bytes using AES

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm aware that there are countless similar questions that have been answered here before, but I still cannot seem to understand the problem I'm facing. I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt file data bytes using AES, but it's not letting me do so. I've tried the following code with a string as input, and it runs like a charm. If I try with the code below, using file data bytes as input, I'm only getting an error. I'm wondering *why* I'm not able to encrypt/decrypt file data bytes properly, and what it is that causes it to fail.

Error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
```

This code is for testing purposes - that's why it's hardcoded.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows;

namespace Dashing
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private RijndaelManaged rij = new RijndaelManaged();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            rij.KeySize = 256;
            rij.BlockSize = 128;
            rij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rij.GenerateKey();
            rij.GenerateIV();

            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5000));
            listener.Start();

            NewClientAndSendData();

            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[20000000];
            int read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            byte[] decryptedData;

            Array.Resize(ref data, read);

            decryptedData = Transform( data, false);

            string path = @"C:\Users\krist\Desktop\testing\10-Terra Nova kap 7 Ressursene.pdf";
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, decryptedData);
        }

        private void NewClientAndSendData()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("192.168.10.122", 5000);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] encryptedData = Transform(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\krist\Desktop\10-Terra Nova kap 7 Ressursene.pdf"), true);

            stream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }


        private byte[] Transform(byte[] data, bool encrypt)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var handler = encrypt ? rij.CreateEncryptor() : rij.CreateDecryptor())
                {
                    using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(ms, handler, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        cstream.FlushFinalBlock();

                        return ms.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code work because you are using the same option when encrypting and decrypting.  The code may not work if a different application encrypt/decrypt the data if it is using a different encryption method.  You are getting a padding error which indicates the padding option isn't match the other application.

Comment: @jdweng Having a different padding method is certainly not the only thing that can cause bad padding errors. Please be very sure when writing comments as we cannot downvote them.

Comment: The streaming is certainly not up to par, if just because of the single stream `Read` call.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what do you mean by that? Is there a problem with the reading?

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes : I believe the padding error message is correct.  There are other error messages that would occur key was wrong for other reasons.  We know the following 1) The key size is valid for the algorithm. 2) The key size is not greater than size for the algorithm. 3) And the keys size is smaller than expected with the padding option turned on.  So either the key is too small or the padding option should be turned off.

Comment: @KristianMjelde Yes, a single `Read` may not read all the data from a stream, only those that are directly available. With a file you usually get all the data, but with a socket that may not be the case (for: `int read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);`. You may get less data that's still a multiple of the block size, for instance, which means you may get a padding error if that's the case.